# BigDecimal NumberFormatException when I execute the application in another computer

Tags: java, bigdecimal, numberformatexception

Hello guys I'm having an error when executing this code
it works perfectly in my computer but when I sent the application to my friend to try it it caused a number format exception, is there a problem with the code? if so why is it working in my computer
ps: I tried the application in another computer and it works

```
double total = 0;
//here there is a for loop changing the total value 
//but in this case (when the application starts) the loop condition will be false
//so the total will stay 0 
String totalS = String.format("%.2f", total);
if (totalS.endsWith(".00")) {
    totalS = totalS.substring(0,totalS.length()-3);
}
lblDa.setText(new BigDecimal(totalS).toPlainString() +" DA");
```

edit: here is the error message

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Character , is neither a decimal digit number, decimal point, nor "e" notation exponential mark.
        at java.base/java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:519)
        at java.base/java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:402)
        at java.base/java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:835)
        at invpack.MainFrame.updateTotal(MainFrame.java:3052)
        at invpack.MainFrame.initialize(MainFrame.java:557)
        at invpack.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:185)
        at invpack.MainFrame$1.run(MainFrame.java:171)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:316)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: Please provide the exception error message (and ideally the full stacktrace, but that's probably not quite as important in this case).

Comment: Also: in the absence of more detailed information my wild guess is that locale differences are to blame for the problem. I.e. the language of the different computers are not set to the same value.

Comment: Does your friend use a comma instead of a dot as decimal separator ?

Comment: @JoachimSauer I posted the error message what do u think ? 
locale differences? how can I solve that

Comment: @BenjaminD u mean when he types or if his computer represent the decimal point with a comma or a dot ?

Comment: Comma versus dot: the French think 1,234.5 is presented as 1.234,5, so locale three times now four!

Comment: Why do you make all your mathematical operations with String and then in the last line convert to BigDecimal and then again convert to String? I think you can do what you want without using BigDecimal :)

Comment: @OnurBaştürk I m using double, the String is just to delete the last .00, and for bigdecimal, I use it to convert the exponential in the double to plaintext

Comment: Please edit your question to paste in the full error stack trace as text. A link will eventually expire, which defeats the purpose of helping others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `String.format` method you are using looks up details about the number format from user preferences: it may use "," instead of "." for the decimal separator, it may even use digits other than 0-9. The rest of your program assumes that the generated string uses ASCII digits and "." for decimal separator.

When you need `String.format` to generate the number in a specific style, pass in a fixed Locale argument:

```
String totalS = String.format(Locale.ROOT, "%.2f", total);
```

On the other hand, it looks like all of this code is there only so that you don't display trailing zeros. There's a more straightforward way to achieve that: use a number format that makes trailing zeros optional.

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
lblDa.setText(formatter.format(total) +" DA");
```

Comment: I m using bigdecimal to convert the exponential in the double to plaintext, 
with String.format(Locale.ROOT, "%.2f", total); it still works for me, but I m waiting for my friend to try it

Comment: The `DecimalFormat` number formatting class also does that, while giving you more control over the format such as formatting `123` as `123` not `123.00`.

Comment: oh I didn't know about it, thanks I will check it out

Answer (score 0):

String s = new DecimalFormat("0.####").format(Double.parseDouble(value));

It will remove any leading zeros from any double value!